# Procedure giving error in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin, procedures

I have tried the following code with and without a delimiter in phpmyadmin. It seems to reject the delimiter when I have present.

I am using 1 and 1 hosting and the `MySQL` version is `5.0`

The error code I specifically get is **`#1064`**`- You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add_person_type_procedure(Person_Type_Value_Description VARCHAR(150) , Create_Date DATETIME ,  Modify_Date DATETIME , Archive CHAR(1))
BEGIN
DECLARE ID VARCHAR(36);
SET ID = (SELECT UUID());
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-programs-defining.html

I think you need "set @ID=..."

Comment: thank you for your reply. I had missed out the @, but the error message is still present. Do you know of anything else it may be?

Comment: I really think you need to use a 'delimiter //' or equivalent.

Comment: with a delimiter I get this error instead:


#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER //'

Comment: You have some larger issue then. That's a pretty basic command. What are you using to edit your procedure?

Comment: I'm trying to create the procedure, I am using phpmyadmin, it is for a website using mysql/php

Comment: check the mysql version. Its possible with phpMyAdmin but might be more exciting.

Comment: thanks, I did extensive research and contacted my host provider, turns out phpmyadmin does support it, and so does my version of mysql, but my host version of phpmyadmin (1 and 1) make it a pain to use them.